# Objective-C: Splitting up a class

Tags: objective-c, class

Let's pretend I have the following three files:

- `MainViewController.h`
- `MainViewController.m`
- `MainViewController.xib`

The `MainViewController.xib` will display a lot of different information to the screen, such as buttons, labels and images.

Let's also pretend that I also have these three files:

- `DisplayController.h`
- `DisplayController.m`
- `DisplayController.xib`

Is it possible, within `MainViewController.m`, to call a method in `DisplayController.m` that is able to change what is being displayed on `MainViewController.xib`?

So, if I want a separate class that will draw the images to `MainViewController.xib`, and a separate class that will draw the buttons to `MainViewController.xib`, how would I go about that? I would imagine that there would need to be some sort of link established between `MainViewController` and `DisplayController` so that `DisplayController` was able to manipulate attributes found in `MainViewController`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need other class? Why not use a protocol?

Comment: A protocol isn't code -- nothing to "share".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can call a static (ie, "+" vs "-") method from essentially anywhere at any time.  This is sometimes the simplest/best way to implement common methods that don't need access to instance variables.

Next, if you have `alloc`ed and `init`ed an instance of `DisplayController`, and you have a pointer to that instance, you can call methods of that instance, even though the view it controls is not being displayed.

And you can, eg, pass into an instance method of `DisplayController` a pointer to a `UIButton` that you want to have modified somehow (say to update its text), even though that `UIButton` is does not "belong" to the `DisplayController`.  Code is code, basically, and the bits don't really care who sets them.

You could even assign the pointer to that `UIButton` to a property in `DisplayController`, so that you could come back later and manipulate it without needing to have the pointer passed in again.

You just need to be careful and not forget that you're dealing with a "foreign" object, and that your current instance variables (other than perhaps its own property) have no relation to it.  It's wise to have some highly-visible comments explaining this.

What you probably can't do (to my knowledge) is somehow link your DisplayController directly to MainViewController.xib (while that xib is simultaneously linked by MainViewController and/or your DisplayController instance is simultaneously linked to DisplayController.xib).  Yeah, there maybe are hokey ways to sort of do it, but they'd be fragile, complex, and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

A .xib file is just an archive, so, yes, any class could open and read that archive.  It sounds like you want to look at the

```
- (NSArray *)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options
```

of the NSBundle class.  This returns an array which is filled with the top level views, and you can navigate down the view hierarchy through the subviews of any view to find the images, labels, or whatever are contained in the .xib file.

So yes, a method in DisplayViewController could load the .xib file and do something with it, or pass it to the MainViewController.